# Laravel validation : difference between numeric and integer?

Tags: laravel, validation

in [laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation) there seems to be an [integer](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-integer) and a [numeric](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#rule-numeric) validation rule. i was wondering what the difference between the both was?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

Integer is like a whole number without fraction: `2, 256, 2048`.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-int.php

Numeric is any number including floating point numbers: `2.478, +0123.45e6`

http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-numeric.php

Comment: In HTML, when using `<input type="number"/>` and validating it on Laravel with `integer` I am getting the `must be an integer` error.

Comment: Just a caveat with `integer`: the validation will pass even if the string contains wihtespace before and after the number being checked. For the application, it will produce an error *"A non well formed numeric value encountered"*. With `numeric`, the application will handle that error properly and ask the user to check their input.

Comment: This is misleading. Laravel is not great at strict typing. if $value is set to (bool)true, then is_int returns false, however `filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false` which Laravel uses for integer validation will return true. So both (bool)true and (int)$x return true according to Laravel's validator.

Answer (score 7):

According to the Laravel's Source Code, both the validations have the following logic.

```
// For rule 'integer'
protected function validateInteger($attribute, $value)
{
    return filter_var($value, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT) !== false;
}

// For rule 'numeric'
protected function validateNumeric($attribute, $value)
{
    return is_numeric($value);
}
```

For more reference dig into the source code of Laravel - [here >>](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.3/src/Illuminate/Validation/Validator.php#L1102)