# How to use other field value in Laravel validation

Tags: laravel, credit-card, laravel-validation

I am using Laravel validation for credit card [here](https://github.com/laravel-validation-rules/credit-card), but I can't make the expiration date work for it needs the `expiration_month` value. This is what I'm doing in my validation:

```
$val = [
    'card_num' => ['required', 'numeric', new CardNumber],
    'card_exp_month' => ['required', 'string', 'between:1:12', CardExpirationMonth('card_exp_year')],
    'card_exp_year' => ['required', 'string', new CardExpirationYear('card_exp_month')],
];
```

This one is returning an error

> Validation rule between requires at least 2 parameters.

Now, how can I use the other fields on this kind of validation?

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo, change the colon to comma:

```
'between:1,12'
```

And I think it's better to validate it as `Integer`:

```
'card_exp_month' => ['required', 'integer', 'between:1,12', CardExpirationMonth('card_exp_year')],
```

Comment: Numeric can be any number (with fraction) but integer is whole number [see this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40434642/laravel-validation-difference-between-numeric-and-integer).